# Filter on the column on which two tables are joined

Tags: sql, join

Are next two queries going to return same result set?

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id = '5' 
--------------------------------
SELECT * FROM tableA a
JOIN tableb b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id = '5'
```

Also, will answer be different if `LEFT JOIN` is used instead of `JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, they will return the same result.

The two will not necessarily return the same result with a `left join`.

Comment: So if I use left join in my query by which of those two columns (`a.id` and `b.id`) should I filter? Or should I use `a.id = '5' or b.id = '5'` in where clause (in case when I use `LEFT JOIN`, cause you said that it wouldn't return same result)?

Comment: @niksrb . . . It depends on what you want.  I would guess `where a.id = 5`, because that is more reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the result will be the same.

With a left join you will get every dataset of both table who got a ID. 
With a join (Inner Join) you will get only the dataset's who a.id = b.id.

This site will explain you how to join https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will. A simple `join` works like an inner join by default. It checks for instances where the item you're joining on exist on both tables. Since you're joining on where `a.id=b.id` the results will be the same.

If you change the type of join to a left, the results will include all `a.id`'s regardless of whether they are equal to 5.